# Is it possible to define a custom movement in vim?

Tags: vim, text-editing

Is it even possible?

What I mean is, many vim commands can take a movement to operate on, can I define a custom movement so that I can tailor my edits to an environment?

The specific command I'm interested in is `gq`, to re-format. I can type `gqip` to re-format a paragraph, `ip` being the movement from the beginning to the end of the current paragraph excluding surrounding whitespace.

Is it possible to define a custom movement to replace `ip` to allow me to, say, re-format comments without touching surrounding code? This would require a movement similar to `ip` but with different conditions for where it starts or ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) article on [creating new text objects](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects), and also at these two Vim plugins that provide [functions for creating custom text objects](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) and [an example](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) of creating custom text objects.

Comment: You should probably expand this answer to briefly cover what those links mention. In particular, that it's omap that does what I want.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser: I would if I understood it better myself. As it is, I just knew where to find more information.